# How to inform system about creating new device?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a little problem with my virtual disk device in Windows Explorer.
After sending IOCTL_VCRYD_MOUNT_VOLUME to device driver, I want it to show up in explorer.  My device successfully mounts (if I kill explorer.exe process in Task Manager and then run it again, I'm able to see my device in drives list), but i can't see it in Windows Explorer (if I don't perform an operation described above).

I haven't found anything appropriate in Kernel Mode, so I tried to use SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_DRIVEADD, SHCNF_PATH, mydrivestring, NULL); with mydrivestring in different formats in User Mode application. But this doesn't help.

So how can i notify Windows Explorer about new disk drive added?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by calling WinAPI BroadcastSystemMessage function

But if someone can tell me how to use SHChangeNotify, I'd be grateful.